# HTML image embed link does not work in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, url, click

could you please help me to solve my problem? Since I am trying to add URL into my image it does not do anything. I have a CSS animation inside of my image. The system is based on wordpress. After the image hover, image is not clickable after the url is set.

The html code looks like this

```
<div class="hover ehover1">
<img class="img-responsive" src="imageSOURCEurl" alt="" />
<div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

When I try to add url it looks like this

```
<div class="hover ehover1">
<a href="URL HERE DOES NOT WORK"><img class="img
responsive" src="imageSOURCEurl"
alt="" /></a>
<div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
#lab_snippet_module .col-lg-3,
#lab_snippet_module .col-md-4,
#lab_snippet_module .col-sm-6,
#lab_snippet_module .col-xs-12 {
  padding: 0!important;
}

#lab_snippet_module {
  background: purple;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.hover,
.hover h2 {
  text-align: center
}

.hover,
.hover .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden
}

.ehover11 .overlay::before,
.ehover12 h2::after,
.ehover7 .overlay::before {
  content: ''
}



.hover button.info,
.hover h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff
}

.navbar-inverse {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #fff
}

.col-lg-3,
.col-md-4,
.col-sm-6,
.col-xs-12 {
  padding: 0
}

.hover {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  cursor: default
}

.hover .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0
}

.hover img {
  display: block;
  position: relative
}

.ehover10 button,
.hover button.info {
  display: inline-block
}

.hover h2 {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6)
}

.hover button.info {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 7px 14px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  margin: 50px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: transparent
}

.hover button.info:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff
}

.ehover5 button.info:hover,
.hover button.nullbutton:hover {
  box-shadow: none
}

.hover button.nullbutton {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}

.ehover4 button.info,
.ehover42 button.info {
  margin: -55px 0 0;
  padding: 73px 90px;
  font-weight: 400;
  border: 1px solid #fff
}

.modal-open .modal,
button:focus {
  outline: 0!important
}

.point {
  cursor: pointer
}

.ehover1 img {
  -webkit-transition: all .4s linear;
  transition: all .4s linear
}

.ehover1 .overlay {
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out
}

.ehover1 h2 {
  -ms-transform: translatey(-100px);
  -webkit-transform: translatey(-100px);
  transform: translatey(-100px);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out
}

.ehover1 button.info {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out
}

.ehover1:hover img {
  -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2)
}

.ehover1:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1
}

.ehover1:hover button.info,
.ehover1:hover h2 {
  opacity: 1;
  -ms-transform: translatey(0);
  -webkit-transform: translatey(0);
  transform: translatey(0)
}

.ehover1:hover button.info {
  -webkit-transition-delay: .2s;
  transition-delay: .2s
}
```

Thank you

Comment: can you try to wrap all of you `div`s with the `a` tag?

Comment: Then I will loose my animation which is made in css.

Comment: When I change all divs into a tags it works but without animation on hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because  `.hover .overlay {}`
has a position absolute. This makes that it will "hide" your ahref functionality.
Make sure your `<a href="#"></a>` is above the overlay to make it clickable.

For example: If I just remove the `position:absolute` from `.hover .overlay {}`, then it works. Check this plunkr as an example: https://plnkr.co/edit/6MuuVZH2LlbxTcCHblxa?p=preview

Comment: Which position in css makes it under the `<a href=">` ?

Comment: .hover .overlay {
  position: absolute; // I guess this will "hide" your <a href>
  top: 0;
  left: 0
}

Comment: Ah, just added an plunkr as an example. But that was not necessary anymore. The description was enough. Have fun coding! :)

Comment: Thank you :) Have a great day